# Uploading a directory recursively iOS AWS S3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to figure out how to upload a directory to S3 for quite some time now using the iOS SDK for AWS.

Currently, I have been having to .zip the directories I have been uploading. Using s3cmd on my EC2 server, I can upload directories no problem. I have also read that it is possible using other SDK's.

This is the code I have now (swift):

```
let folderPath = DocumentFolder.stringByAppendingString("/folderPath/folder")
let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
            uploadRequest.bucket = "my-bucket"
            uploadRequest.serverSideEncryption = AWSS3ServerSideEncryption.AwsKms
            uploadRequest.body = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: folderPath)
            uploadRequest.key = "/\(folderName)/"


            AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager().upload(uploadRequest)
```

However, this causes me to receive an NSInvalidArgumentException.

This is the exact error:

> 2016-02-26 15:11:10.672 Q-Gate[1002:417054] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData initWithBytes:length:copy:deallocator:]: absurd length: 18446744073709551615, maximum size: 9223372036854775808 bytes'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x181e55900 0x1814c3f80 0x181e55848 0x182743ef4 0x182743e38 0x1001ccdd0 0x1001cd7fc 0x18242287c 0x182420eb4 0x182420d74 0x182420ca4 0x1824a6ee4 0x182420c30 0x101e81bb0 0x101e8b354 0x182417a88 0x181d390ac 0x18241796c 0x18241782c 0x182417658 0x181e0cefc 0x181e0c990 0x181e0a690 0x181d39680 0x1824a9434 0x182817c40 0x181abfb28 0x181abfa8c 0x181abd028)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

If I change the path to the .zip, it uploads no problem.

Does anyone know the proper way to upload a directory to s3 using their iOS SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass a directory as `body`. You need to recursively list files in the directory and call `- upload:` for each file.

---

AWSS3TransferManager() is not a valid initializer for this class. The `reason` for the exception is

```
`- init` is not a valid initializer. Use `+ defaultS3TransferManager` or `+ S3TransferManagerForKey:` instead.
```

You need to use `AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()` or `AWSS3TransferManager(forKey: "YourKey")`. Read [API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3TransferManager.html#//api/name/defaultS3TransferManager) for more details.

Comment: I accidentally left out that portion when modifying my code for better readability in this post. In my actual project, that is how I am calling it.